# Linked List traversal skips values

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm new to pointers and I'm a bit confused.
I have written a function which merges and sorts two sorted linked lists. However, when I print the list after calling the function it does not have all the values of the new merged list. While debugging the code and examining the variables and memory locations, it looks like it skips over the locations and just jumps to the last memory location. After the function executes I need to have the values in a new list and leaving list1 and list2 empty. This is my method in the header file:

```
template <class Type>
void orderedLinkedList<Type>::mergeLists(orderedLinkedList<Type> &list1, orderedLinkedList<Type> &list2)
{
    nodeType<Type> *lastSmall; //pointer to the last node of the merged list.
    nodeType<Type> *first1 = list1.first;
    nodeType<Type> *first2 = list2.first;

    if (list1.first == NULL){ //first sublist is empty
        this->first = list2.first;
        list2.first = NULL;
    }
    else if (list2.first == NULL){ // second sublist is empty
        this->first = list1.first;
        list1.first = NULL;
    }
    else{
        if (first1->info < first2->info){ //Compare first nodes
            this->first = first1;
            first1 = first1->link;
            lastSmall = this->first;
        }
        else{
            this->first = first2;
            first2 = first2->link;
            lastSmall = this->first;
        }


    while (first1 != NULL && first2 != NULL)
    {
        if(first1->info < first2->info){
            lastSmall->link = first1;
            lastSmall = lastSmall->link;
            first1 = first1->link;
        }
        else{
            lastSmall->link = first2;
            lastSmall = lastSmall->link;
            first2 = first2->link;
        }
    } //end while

    if (first1 == NULL) //first sublist exhausted first
        lastSmall->link = first2;
    else //second sublist exhausted first
        lastSmall->link = first1;

    list1.first = NULL;
    list1.last = NULL;

    list2.first = NULL;
    list2.last = NULL;
    }
}
```

Then in my main.cpp I have:

```
int main()
{

    orderedLinkedList<int> list1;
    orderedLinkedList<int> list2;
    orderedLinkedList<int> newList;

    list1.insert(2);
    list1.insert(6);
    list1.insert(7);
    list2.insert(3);
    list2.insert(5);
    list2.insert(8);

    newList.mergeLists(list1, list2);
    newList.print();
    return 0;
}
```

My print function just in case:

```
template <class Type>
void linkedListType<Type>::print() const
{
    nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the list

    current = first;    //set current so that it points to
                        //the first node
    while (current != NULL) //while more data to print
    {
        cout << current->info << " ";
        current = current->link;
    }
}//end print
```

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here? The output should be 2 3 5 6 7 8 but instead it's 2 3 7 8.

Thanks

EDIT:
Here is my insertion function. Note that this function is from the book I'm working with. It is included in the same class that I need to add the mergeLists method to. It is written specifically for ordered lists:

```
template<class Type>
void orderedLinkedList<Type>::insert(const Type& newItem)
{
    nodeType<Type> *current;
    nodeType<Type> *trailCurrent;
    nodeType<Type> *newNode;

    bool found;

    newNode = new nodeType<Type>;
    newNode->info = newItem;
    newNode->link = NULL;

    //case1 list is empty
    if(this->first == NULL)
    {
        this->first = newNode;
        this->last = newNode;
        this->count++;
    }
    else //if the list is not empty
    {
        current = this->first;
        found = false;

        while(current != NULL && !found)
        {
            if(current->info >= newItem)
                found = true;
            else
            {
                trailCurrent = current;
                current = current->link;
            }

        //case2 insert newNode at the head
        if(current == this->first)
        {
            newNode->link = this->first;
            this->first = newNode;
            this->count++;
        }
        else //case 3 
        {
            trailCurrent->link = newNode;
            newNode->link = current;

            if(current == NULL)
                this->last = newNode;

        this->count++;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

The 3 cases as according to the book are:

- Case 1:

  The list is initially empty. The node containing the new item is the only node
  and, thus, the first node in the list.
- Case 2:

  The new item is smaller than the smallest item in the list. The new item goes at
  the beginning of the list. In this case, we need to adjust the list’s head pointer—
  that is, first. Also, count is incremented by 1.
- Case 3:

  The item is to be inserted somewhere in the list.
- Case 3a:

  The new item is larger than all the items in the list. In this case, the new
  item is inserted at the end of the list. Thus, the value of current is NULL
  and the new item is inserted after trailCurrent. Also, count is incremented
  by 1.
- Case 3b:

  The new item is to be inserted somewhere in the middle of the list. In this
  case, the new item is inserted between trailCurrent and current.
  Also, count is incremented by 1.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Why not use std::merge() http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/merge/

Comment: @MichaelSurette The book I'm working through has this as an exercise question where I must write my own code instead of using the STL.

Comment: @user931018 Code::Blocks uses gdb internally if I remember correctly, one of the most powerful debuggers for C++. What is the limiting part?

Comment: You give the expected value but not the results you get.  Please make it easy for us and give both.

Comment: I see one potential problem (though not happening in your example), if either list is empty (list1.first or list2.first are null) lastSmall does not get initialized before it hits one of the lastSmall->link statements in your while loop.

Comment: @MichaelSurette Apologies. I've updated the question with the actual result. It only seems to return 4 values regardless of how many values are in the list. Ex, if list1 = { 2, 6, 7, 10, 13 } and list2 = { 3, 5, 8, 12, 15 } it only prints 2 3 10 12.

Comment: @Marker I haven't done any explicit error checking for empty lists as the exercise assumes both lists have sorted values.

Comment: One thing that always helps me when working with data structures, sketch it out on paper and walk through your code modifying your sketch as needed at each step.

Comment: @user931018, "I haven't done any explicit error checking for empty lists" -> well your first two if statements check for empty lists.

Comment: @Marker The indentation is confusing. If any list is empty, `lastSmall` is never used.

Comment: @Max Vollmer, OK I see that now, thanks.

Comment: I just ran a [short program based on your code](https://onlinegdb.com/H1XC4QnPX), and it outputs `2 3 5 6 7 8` as expected. Please provide a fully compilable [MCVE], there has to be something else going on that is not included in your code example.

Comment: Maybe your `insert` method has a bug and the two lists don't actually contain all values?

Comment: Your merge function works for me too.  You didn't post your insert code so I wrote one.  Like Max Vollmer said, maybe your insert function is dropping nodes.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's efforts in trying to help. I've added my insertion method in my original question. This is directly from the book and it is included in the same class as the mergeLists that I need to add.

Comment: Okay, whatever that book is, throw it away.

Answer (score 2):

The bug is in your insertion method. When you call `print` on the lists after inserting, you will note that the last value gets overriden:

```
list1.insert(2); list1.print();
list1.insert(6); list1.print();
list1.insert(7); list1.print();
list2.insert(3); list2.print();
list2.insert(5); list2.print();
list2.insert(8); list2.print();
```

will output:

> 2
>   2 6
>   2 7
>   3
>   3 5
>   3 8

This is because every iteration `trailCurrent->link = newNode;` gets called, cutting of the list the first time this happens.

So for example when `7` is inserted in `list1`, the loop will first set `trailCurrent->link` to `7` when `trailCurrent` is `2`, and then continue and set `trailCurrent->link` to `7` when `trailCurrent` is `6`. But since `2` now points to `7` and not to `6`, the chain is lost, and you're stuck with only `2` and `7`.

**Get another book**

The book you are using to learn this is outdated. C style pointers and manual memory allocation should not be used in modern C++. Try to get a modern book that teaches how to use smart pointers and modern collections, and that teaches proper debugging techniques, so you can easily detect problems as the one you stumbled over now.

Comment: Not sure if this counts as a "comment" as per the guidelines. But thanks a lot for your efforts Max, it's appreciated. I am almost ashamed to say that I don't believe it's the book that was at fault, but rather myself. After staring at my insertion method for about an hour I saw the problem. See the "while(current != NULL && !found)" loop in my insertion statement. It seems I foolishly inserted a semi-colon after the while loop. After removing it and the closing semi-colon following "this->count++;" at the end of the method, the code seems to work fine. It displays the results as it should.

Comment: This will likely be moved to chat, but could you please elaborate more on what you meant by "This is because every iteration trailCurrent->link = newNode; gets called, cutting of the list the first time this happens."? When I follow the logic it seems fine and after solving my problem above it does produce the results as it should. As for the book, it was unfortunately assigned to me by my university so I cannot switch from it. For interest sake the book is "Data Structures Using C++ 2nd Edition" by D. S. Malik. Published in 2010, it is quite old as you said.

Comment: I can't seem to edit my comments. I of course mean curly bracket, not semi-colon.

Comment: @user931018 By removing the brackets, you have moved the code you labeled *case2* and *case3* out of the loop. This is where `trailCurrent->link = newNode;` gets called, and because it was inside the loop before, it got called every iteration. With your change it is only called once, after the loop has finished.

Comment: The author of the book seems to be a big fan of obfuscation. They didn't use curly brackets for the `while` loop, which does work in that case, but it makes it super hard to read, and is prone to introduce bugs later when code is changed and such things overlooked. There are plenty such places in that code. It's really poor coding style. Sad that this is used in a university.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who has tried to help. In the end it was a simple logic error. 
I inadvertently added a curly bracket to the end of my while loop in my insertion method which resulted in the loop executing code that it wasn't supposed to more than once causing strange behavior. See the corrected code below:

```
while(current != NULL && !found)
    { //<-- Removed this

    //code

    this->count++;
    }
    } //<-- Removed this
```

And now the working code is:

```
template<class Type>
void orderedLinkedList<Type>::insert(const Type& newItem)
{
    nodeType<Type> *current;
    nodeType<Type> *trailCurrent;
    nodeType<Type> *newNode;

    bool found;

    newNode = new nodeType<Type>;
    newNode->info = newItem;
    newNode->link = NULL;

    //case1 list is empty
    if(this->first == NULL)
    {
        this->first = newNode;
        this->last = newNode;
        this->count++;
    }
    else //if the list is not empty
    {
        current = this->first;
        found = false;

        while(current != NULL && !found)
            if(current->info >= newItem)
                found = true;
            else
            {
                trailCurrent = current;
                current = current->link;
            }

        //case2 insert newNode at the head
        if(current == this->first)
        {
            newNode->link = this->first;
            this->first = newNode;
            this->count++;
        }
        else //case 3 insert newNode anywher in the list
        {
            trailCurrent->link = newNode;
            newNode->link = current;

            if(current == NULL)
                this->last = newNode;

        this->count++;
        }
    }
}
```